# No visible interface for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completion

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I have a UIViewController derived class which uses the method `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)`, like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Since the compiler complains with a warning saying that this method is deprecated, I have changed it to the suggested replacement, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But now, a get an error in that line of code saying "No visible @interface for  declares the selector `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

I can't see what's the problem, since both methods are defined in **UIViewController.h**, and my class derives from that class.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was my fault. 
The new method is

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

not

```
[self dismiss**Modal**ViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thank you all, and excuse me for my silly question.